# Magento 2. How to create StoreView in System.xml

Tags: magento2, configuration, system.xml

How to create Store View in System.xml. I can explain it with image given below 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it...
create new class in

> Vender\Module\Model\Config\Source

```
<?php

namespace Vender\Module\Model\Config\Source;
/**
* @api
* @since 100.0.2
*/
class Stores implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{
   /**
    * Options getter
    *
    * @return array
    */
   public function toOptionArray()
   {

       $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
       $storeManager = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');

       $storeManagerDataList = $storeManager->getStores();
       $options = array();

        foreach ($storeManagerDataList as $key => $value)
        {
              $options[] = ['label' => $value['name'],  'value' => $key ];
        }
        return $options;
   }

}
```

after that in configuration (System.xml)

> Vender\Module\etc\adminhtml\system.xml
>   add these lines

```
<field id="storeview" translate="label" type="multiselect"
                    sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Hide for StoreViews</label>
                    <comment>Product price will be hidden for the selected StoreViews only.</comment>
                    <source_model>Vender\Module\Model\Config\Source\Stores</source_model>
                    <depends>
                        <field id="enabled">1</field>
                    </depends>
                </field>
```

[image]

then you'll get storetypes in configuration.

Comment: Works for me on 2.3.4, Just a note it might be good idea to use DI in constructor instead which I have and is working fine.